# "Warning: array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in user_user_presave()"

Tags: users

I get the following warning when executing my module:

> Warning: array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in user_user_presave() (line 1278 of C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\modules\user\user.module).

Line 1278 is the following one.

```
$edit['roles'] = array_filter($edit['roles']);
```

The function containing it is the following one.

```
function user_user_presave(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  if ($category == 'account' || $category == 'register') {
    if (!empty($edit['picture_upload'])) {
      $edit['picture'] = $edit['picture_upload'];
    }
    // Delete picture if requested, and if no replacement picture was given.
    elseif (!empty($edit['picture_delete'])) {
      $edit['picture'] = NULL;
    }
    // Prepare user roles.
    if (isset($edit['roles'])) {
      $edit['roles'] = array_filter($edit['roles']);
    }
  }

  // Move account cancellation information into $user->data.
  foreach (array('user_cancel_method', 'user_cancel_notify') as $key) {
    if (isset($edit[$key])) {
      $edit['data'][$key] = $edit[$key];
    }
  }
}
```

Where I've used this in my custom module:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  global $base_url;
  //replace roles checkboxes in registration form with select field
  if ($form_id == 'user_register_form') {  
    $form['account']['roles']['#type'] = 'select';
    $form['account']['roles']['#required'] = TRUE;
    $form['account']['roles']['#multiple'] = FALSE;
    $form['account']['notify']['#default_value'] = 1;
    $custom_submit_handler = array('_mymodule_user_presave_roles');
    $form['#submit'] = array_merge($custom_submit_handler, $form['#submit']);
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][0] = '_mymodule_user_presave_roles';
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][1] = 'user_register_submit';
  }
}

function _mymodule_user_presave_roles($form, &$form_state) {
  global $user;
  if (isset($user->roles[3])) {
    $_SESSION['presave_roles'] = $form_state['input']['roles'];
  }
  else {
    foreach ($form_state['user']->roles as $key => $value) {
      if($key != 2) {
        $_SESSION['presave_roles'] = $key;
      }
    }
  }
}

function mymodule_user_update(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  if(!empty($_SESSION['presave_roles'])) {
    db_delete('users_roles')->condition('uid',$account->uid)->execute();
    db_insert('users_roles')->fields(array('uid'=>$account->uid,'rid'=>$_SESSION['presave_roles']))->execute();
    unset($_SESSION['presave_roles']);
  }
}

function mymodule_user_insert(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  if(!empty($_SESSION['presave_roles'])) {
    db_delete('users_roles')->condition('uid',$account->uid)->execute();
    db_insert('users_roles')->fields(array('uid'=>$account->uid,'rid'=>$_SESSION['presave_roles']))->execute();
    unset($_SESSION['presave_roles']);
  }
}

function _mymodule_user_roles($membersonly = FALSE, $permission = NULL) {
  $query = db_select('role', 'r');
  $query->addTag('translatable');
  $query->fields('r', array('rid', 'name'));
  $query->orderBy('weight');
  $query->orderBy('name');
  if (!empty($permission)) {
    $query->innerJoin('role_permission', 'p', 'r.rid = p.rid');
    $query->condition('p.permission', $permission);
  }
  $result = $query->execute();
  $roles = array();
  foreach ($result as $role) {
    switch ($role->rid) {
      // We only translate the built in role names
      case DRUPAL_ANONYMOUS_RID:
        if (!$membersonly) {
          $roles[$role->rid] = t($role->name);
        }
        break;
      case DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID:
        //$roles[$role->rid] = t($role->name);
        break;
      default:
        $roles[$role->rid] = $role->name;
    }
  }
  return $roles;
}
```

**Note: The above implementation I've made, since I want to provide one and only one role per user in Drupal.**

Comment: Check $edit['roles'] is an array.

Comment: What do you mean by "I have overridden it"? May you show how exactly you have overridden it?

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Thanks for the suggestion, editing my question.

Comment: Based on what you've provided, I can't see where $edit["roles"] is clobbered. Do you have a hook_user_presave() function in your module?

Comment: Function from your module starts with `_` - it means it's not a hook, but something used by other functions. So what uses it? and where is `$_SESSION['presave_roles']` read? And shot in the dark - why in the foreach you write to the same index all the time, shouldn't it be `$_SESSION['presave_roles'][] = $key;` instead?

Comment: I've updated the QUESTION, please check if it can help.